# How to scale proportional along the local axis of joined objects?

Tags: transforms

How to scale proportional along the local axis of 2 or more joined objects?
These two objects are joined and need to scale them in XYZ in their local axis.
when using The Scale Gizmo, How to scale proportionally? Most 3D gizmos have a cube icon in the center and it scales in all axis, how to do this in blender?

[image: scale proportional in all axis]

[image: explode]

[image: mergeTextureWTF]

Comment: have you tried Alt S (Shrink/Fatten) in Edit mode?

Comment: There is a different issue with all the parts exploding, but yes it does scale corectly in edit mode.
is there a way to do this in object mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Edit* mode you can use the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Shrink/Fatten* operation. Make sure that the faces are not splitted (select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*. If you want to do it in *Object* mode you can use the *Displace* modifier and play with the *Strength* value.

[image]

If you want to make them bigger but not fatter, activate the *Individual Origins* option in the *Transform Pivot Point* panel, and scale:

[image]

[image]

You can't do that in *Object* mode, unless your 2 meshes are separate as 2 objects (in that case make sure that the origin of each object is set to their geometry).